# Incompatible type for method. Can't convert java.lang.String to char using string.replace

Tags: java

I am retrieving a string in a resultset and then trying to make one of the string values safe by replacing any instances of a double quote. I am getting an incompatible type error though, and can't figure out why. I've looked at the API docs and it hasn't helped!

```
String docName = rs.getString("DOCNAME");
String safeDocName = docName.replace("\"","");
```

The incompatible type error points to the first " inside the replace brackets in my debugger.

Comment: That's simply not valid Java at the moment - you're missing semi-colons on your declarations, and the type name is `String` rather than `string`. Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Also let us know the version of Java you're building against.

Answer (score 6):

You must be compiling for java 1.4 or less, which only knows `String.replace(char, char)`. Since java 1.5 `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` was introduced (for Strings). Check to see the javac option `-source 1.4` / `-target 1.4`.

Comment: Many thanks - I am indeed compiling against 1.4. It's an ancient app that is still being maintained, so that answers the question. Now to figure out how to achieve the same with a char when I need to escape the character!

Comment: Use `replaceAll("\"", "")`. Regex was just introduced.